# Topshelf, Owin selfhost, F# and explicit fields

Tags: f#, owin, topshelf

I've installed the package Topshelf.FSharp, and there is an example of how to use it here:

https://gist.github.com/haf/4252121

Part of the example defines an "Svc" (service) class like this:

```
type Svc() =
  member x.Start() =
    printfn "Started"
  member x.Stop() =
    printfn "Stopped"
```

With Owin selfhost you call one of the various static overloads of `IDisposable WebApp.Start(...)` to start a web server, and then dispose it to stop it. In C#, if you want to combine Topshelf and Owin, you can store the IDisposable result of Start() in a private local field of the Svc class when Start() is called, and then call Dispose() on it in the Stop() method.

In F# you can declare an unitialized field of type IDisposable using "explicit fields" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469494.aspx), but this seems somewhat awkward, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use an explicit field to produce an "uninitialized" `IDisposable` value. For example, to define a restartable service, you can use an implicit `webApp` field like this:

```
// Example 1: Using an implicit mutable IDisposable field.  
type Svc() =
    let mutable webApp = null

    member __.Start() = 
        if webApp = null then webApp <- WebApp.Start<Startup> "http://localhost:12345"

    member __.Stop() = 
        if webApp <> null then webApp.Dispose(); webApp <- null

// Example 2: Using an implicit mutable IDisposable option field.  
type Svc'() =
    let mutable webApp = None

    member __.Start() = 
        match webApp with 
            | Some _ -> () 
            | None -> webApp <- Some(WebApp.Start<Startup> "http://localhost:12345")

    member __.Stop() = 
        match webApp with 
            | Some webAppValue -> webAppValue.Dispose(); webApp <- None
            | None -> ()
```

If the service does not have to be restartable, I would use an (immutable) implicit lazy field instead, as @Tom suggested.

Comment: I guess by "idempotent" you mean idempotent even in the case someone has called "stop"? Otherwise if I use a lazy field and someone calls start, then stop, then start again, the 2nd call to start will fail to do anything, because the lazy value will already have been forced?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant (somewhat vaguely) by "idempotent". However, I have now replaced "idempotent" with "restartable", which is more to the point.

Answer (score 1):

Could you make the member a [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)  instead and have it automatically initialise when it is first accessed? I am not quite sure of the requirements of F# in this case i.e. why exactly this is a problem, but for deferred initialisation, Lazy would seem to be a good choice.

Comment: my original question was misguided, it turns out you can declare an unitialized field of type IDisposable using "explicit fields", although it seems a really messy solution